# Only generate source files if definitions have changed ant

Tags: java, ant

I run a script that generates some java code based on definition files. I want to avoid running this task if the definition files have not changed.

```
<target name="generate" depends="init">
<exec executable="${codeGenTool-path}">
  <arg value="${definitionFolder}" />
  <arg value="${generatedFolder}" />
</exec>
</target>
```

I looked at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html but It seems like I must have a single target file to compare to. The code generation tool creates a folder containing many source files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good use case for the [`outofdate` task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/outofdate.html) from [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net):

```
<outofdate>
  <sourcefiles>
    <fileset dir="${definitionFolder}" />
  </sourcefiles>
  <targetfiles>
    <fileset dir="${generatedFolder}" />
  </targetfiles>
  <sequential>
    <exec executable="${codeGenTool-path}">
      <arg value="${definitionFolder}" />
      <arg value="${generatedFolder}" />
    </exec>
  </sequential>
</outofdate>
```

This will check every file under the `definitionFolder` against every file under the `generatedFolder` - you might want to constrain the filesets more tightly, e.g. with `includes="**/*.def"` or whatever is the relevant file extension.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid "third party" tasks then you could use a `dependset` task to check the target files against the source ones.

```
<target name="generate" depends="check.generate, do.generate" />

<target name="check.generate">
  <dependset>
    <srcfileset dir="${definitionFolder}" />
    <targetfileset dir="${generatedFolder}" />
  </dependset>

  <condition property="gen.required">
    <resourcecount count="0" when="equal">
      <fileset dir="${generatedFolder}" />
    </resourcecount>
  </condition>
</target>

<target name="do.generate" if="gen.required">
  <exec ....>
</target>
```

The `dependset` task deletes *all* the target files if *any* of them are older than any of the source files, so we can make `do.generate` conditional - it will run if there are no files in the `generatedFolder`, which will be the case when either it's never been run before, or the generated files were out of date.